# How to use MyBatis instead of Spring DataSource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

My goal is to configure everything using MyBatis for the SQL operations. Every tutorial I found does not mention about `application.properties` yet if I did not configure `application.properties` it will throws an error.

**I wish to not configure `spring.datasource.*`, instead I wish to configure everything using MyBatis.**

Error #1

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Error #2

```
WARN 2560 --- [           main] o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.]' package. Please check your configuration.
```

==== This configuration does not throws Error #1.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=javatest
spring.datasource.username=java
spring.datasource.password=java
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<configuration xmlns="http://mybatis.org/schema/mybatis-config">
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"></transactionManager>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=javatest"/>
                <property name="username" value="java"/>
                <property name="password" value="java"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
</configuration>
```

partial pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you using `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` dependency?

Comment: @goldthelocks It turns out I does use it.

Comment: are you using `spirng-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your dependency?

Comment: @Shawrup no I did not. I will psot my pom.xml.

Comment: @goldthelocks it turns out mybatis-spring-boot-starter did not use `.xml` at all. I will take a look, it does reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: Sure, I also added an answer which you can take a look at.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below property to your `application.properties` to define the location of your mybatis config:

```
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis-config.xml
```

Source: http://mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/#Configuration

Comment: I tried yours on my ongoing project and it still throws a warn `o.m.s.mapper.ClassPathMapperScanner      : No MyBatis mapper was found in '[com.example.bankaccount]' package. Please check your configuration.`

Comment: How do you currently define where your mappers files are?

Comment: Try to add this to your application class: @MapperScan(basePackages = "com.example.bankaccount")

Comment: @goldthelocks I define my mapper in `.xml` for example `resources/builder/User_LoginMapper.xml`. I configure the `<mapper resource />` in `resources/mybatis-config.xml`

Comment: @znurgl this works if you do not use `mybatis-config.xml` and `User_LoginMapper.xml`. Please take a look the difference between this 2 source code (one is using annotation and does not use XML at all) https://github.com/kidfrom/g2_java/tree/main/etc/mssqlserver and the other one is my ongoing banking project (it use XML)  https://github.com/kidfrom/g2_java/tree/main/Bank_Account/java/bankaccount

Comment: I checked the project you provided from github. Try to annotate your DAO classes with `@Mapper`. You may also check the sample project from mybatis documentation which has similar setup with yours: https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter/tree/master/mybatis-spring-boot-samples/mybatis-spring-boot-sample-xml

Comment: @goldthelocks I will try it on the `github.com/kidfrom/g2_java/tree/main/etc/mssqlserver`. I found using @Mapper will require the editing of the `service` folder and deletion of the `repository` folder, since I use the `REST - Service - Repository` pattern.